# How do I call a method from a parent of a parent of an inherited class?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class TimsOrder {

    private int size;
    private String name;
    private static TimsProduct[] items;

    private TimsOrder(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public double getRetailPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    private static void orderItem(TimsProduct item) {
        Donut chocolate = Donut.create();
        item = chocolate;
    }

    public static TimsOrder create() {
        items = new TimsProduct[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            orderItem(items[i]);
        }
        TimsOrder order = new TimsOrder("OrderName", 1); //Where 1 is the # of items
    }

    public double getAmountDue() {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Testpoint");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total = total + (((TimsProduct) items[i]).getRetailPrice()); //Line with issue
        }
        return total;
    }
}

public abstract class TimsProduct extends Commodity {
    private String name;
    private double cost;
    private double price;

    @Override
    public double getRetailPrice(){
        System.out.println("Testpoint2");
        return price;
    }
}

public class Donut extends TimsProduct {
    private String description;
    private int calorieCount;

    private Donut(String name, String description, double cost, double price, int calorieCount) {
        super(name, cost, price);
        this.description = description;
        this.calorieCount = calorieCount;
    }

    public static Donut create() {
        Donut chocolate = new Donut("Chocolate", "Glazed", 0.30, 0.99, 500);
        return chocolate;
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
TimsOrder t = TimsOrder.create();
System.out.println(t);
System.out.printf("Total Price: $%.2f\n", t.getAmountDue());
```

I realize that t.items has 0 values which is the problem here. What I do not know is why these values are not there.

If anyone wants to see the files:
Commodity.java
https://pastebin.com/raw/9sWbDWV8

TimsProduct.java extends commodity
https://pastebin.com/raw/jzgfkd0P

TimsOrder.java
https://pastebin.com/raw/vc0VtDq6

Donut.java extends TimsProduct
https://pastebin.com/raw/w7iEQG1H

Comment: The relevant code must be *in the question itself*. Not at pastebin.

Comment: What is the Type of items? Can't find any product type. Do you mean TimsProduct?

Comment: Sorry I have updated it. I do mean TimsProduct. I am attempting to debug it with a break point

Comment: Please do follow @JBNizet's advice -- all code must be in your question itself as code-formatted text. Understand that this isn't so much a *help* site, but rather a *question and answer* site where Q & A's are supposed to help all, not just the original poster.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Nice nickname, Monthy ;)

Comment: Please look up the [mcve] link. It will tell you what we need you to post code-wise.

Answer (score 1):

This is an initial response based on what little the OP provided.

You are not overriding your getters in your deriving classes (and the basic implementation in the base can not compile) :

```
public abstract class Commodity {

    public double getProductionCost() {
       // no return value!
    }

    public double getRetailPrice() {
       // no return value!         
    }
}

public abstract class TimsProduct extends Commodity{
    private String name;
    private double cost;
    private double price;


    public TimsProduct(String name, double cost, double price){
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.price = price;

    } 

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    // no @Override!
    public double getProductionCost(){
        return cost;
}
    // no @Override!
    public double getRetailPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ("Name is:  " + name + "cost is: " + cost + "price is: " + price );
    }
}
```

Comment: As an important side note - the rest of the code is a mishmash of Factory DPs, UI input handling code and business logic code. I would highly suggested to review and redesign this code.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I have attempted to add Overrides to the suggested functions but it still doesnt work. TimsProduct is an empty array, so I'm trying to debug that. Cheers

Comment: What exactly does not work ? We need more information in order to help you out, buddy....

Comment: Rann, we've tried to coax @user2372210 to improve his question, but to no avail. :(

Comment: Apologies, but i'm in the process of rewriting it..